# Rich content in Strapi rendering with no space between paragraphs

Tags: nuxt.js, strapi, markdown-it

I'm using markdown-it with `nuxt` to render my article content (`rich text`) to `html` from `strapi`. The text renders but the spacing between paragraphs is not included. I can use `<br>` tag on rich text editor on `strapi` to create line breaks but shouldn't `strapi` automatically do this?

```
 <div v-html="$md.render(articles.content || 'No content available')"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think there is a bug in strapi currently that prevents it from recording single line breaks in the rich text editor (When you press the enter-key in the rich text editor) You can use the following work arounds:
In the Strapi Rich Text Editor:

1. Double space to record line-breaks where ever you need them in the rich text editor. This will add the `<br>` tag. For multiple line breaks, repeat.
   For example:

> This is First Para.(Double Space-key then press Enter-key here)This is Second Para

HTML Output:

```html
<p>This is first Para.<br>This is Second Para</p>
```

2. Press Enter "twice" to create a new Paragraph tag. This will separate the two lines as two different Paragraph elements.

> This is First Para.(Double Enter-key here)This is Second Para

HTML Output:

```html
<p>This is First Para.</p>
<p>This is Second Para</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error while using strapi and to fix this Bug for my Next app i used the code below:

```html
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: content }}
```